# Visual Studio Xamarin Android Добавление компонентов Google Play Services

Tags: android, c#, visual-studio, xamarin, google-play-services

Пытаюсь добавить Google Play Services для проекта Android по этому мануалу [https://developer.xamarin.com/guides...*2*-_maps_api/](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides..._2_-_maps_api/)

[image: Google Play Services]

У меня при добавлении компонентов просит войти в xamarin account

[image: Xamarin Account]

После входа:

[image: Error]

Может кто знает, что нужно сделать, чтобы войти в Xamarin Components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема, скорее всего, заключалась в Visual Studio 2017 RC Community, так как она является версией release candidate, переустановка среды на Visual Studio 2015 Community решило проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Была такая же проблема. Уже не помню с какой версией плагина для VS. Однако мне помогла только переустановка плагина. N

Если проблема не уйдет после переустановки. То есть еще один вариант установки. Почти все библиотеки можно смело скачать из NutGet Gallery.

К примеру Google Service:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement/

Как вариант проверте лицензию в аккаунте https://www.xamarin.com/.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В вашем случае должно быть Visual Studio Community. Вместо Enterprise.

Comment: У меня была проблема, скорее всего, из-за visual studio 2017 RC Community, либо что-то "криво" стало, либо недоработка RC-версии... Переустановил среду на VS 2015 Community, там всё вошло без проблем. Мне надо было, чтобы в Components загрузился Google Play Services - Maps, через nuget не пробовал, но, возможно, он добавит в reference только package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.

Comment: Ну с  visual studio 2017 RC .  Есть такие проблемы. Поэтому пока не использую. Google Play Services - Maps тоже есть в NutGet Gallery. Просто добавление  библиотек через Components. Имеет ряд преимуществ. 2 основных. Первое это быстрый доступ к примеру или примерам. И инструкции как пользоваться компонентом. Второе, это что visual studio историю установки компонентов. Создали новый проект. Get Components. и видим всю историю.